# Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

Probably I'm missing something but the most simple "Worksheet_Change" doesn't work at all. The code is placed in the correct worksheet and is exactly the same as in samples I have found in my search to solve the problem. Please ignore the lines that start with "'" as they will be part of the code after the issue is solved. I've simplified the code in trying to localize the issue but as I said, even this simple code doesn't work, even if I use a new Workbook with only one sheet. As said, I might be missing something completely simple but for the moment, I don't know what it is. Thank you.

Jan

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)


'    Dim KeyCells As Range

'    Set KeyCells = Range("Orders[Nieuw]")
    
'    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("Orders[Nieuw]"), Target) _
'       Is Nothing Then
'    If Target.Address = "$C$10" Then

Application.EnableEvents = False

'    If Target.Value = "Ja" Then

MsgBox "This Code Runs When Cell A1 Changes!"

Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5


'    Range("AG2").Select
'    Selection.Copy
    
'    Range("Ordernummerbereik").Select
'    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
'    SendKeys ("{ESC}")
'    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

'    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `EnableEvents` currently set to False?

Comment: `Target As Excel.Range` Where are you executing this? it should be just `Range` not `Excel.Range`. Also, did you type the whole code or are you using the event created in the VBA editor?

Comment: Yes, EnableEvents is set False.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - `Excel.Range` is totally fine.

Comment: I've seen an exemple where Excel.Range was used. It doesn't make a difference if I make the change. I've used the first line of code that was generatd

Comment: I've used the first line of code that was generated by using the event. I have replaced it by manual entry but  this has no effect.

Comment: @Jan - if `EnableEvents` is `False`, then of course nothing will happen.

Comment: What exactly is the connection between `Range("Orders[Nieuw]")`, `$C$10` and `A1`? Where is `Orders` located? Where is `Range("Ordernummerbereik")` located and is it one cell only? If events are turned off, run this simple procedure `Sub Enable() : Application.EnableEvents = True: End Sub` to enable them.

Comment: Please ignore the code lines starting with " ' " as they are not part of the issue and will be activated and completed later. Even the simple code of only six lines doesn't work for a reason I cannot figure out. But I will keep trying and searching.

Answer (score 2):

You probably ended up in `EnableEvents = False` and therefore no events will be executed anymore including the `Worksheet_Change` event.

When using `Application.EnableEvents = False` make sure you use proper error handling that returns it to `True` otherwise if an error occurs it stays `False` until you close Excel.

Example for error handling

```
Public Sub Example()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Goto EventsOn
    
    ' your code here


    
EventsOn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number Then Err.Raise Err.Number  ' show the error message

End Sub
```

That means if any error occurs in `your code` it jumps to `EventsOn:` turns events on and throws the error message. This way you ensure that `Events` are always turned on in case of an error.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can reproduce your problem is by setting `EnableEvents` to false outside of the sub. Perhaps it crashed at some stage leaving events disabled?

Incidentally you can replace the copy and paste with

```
Range("Ordernummerbereik").Value = Range("AG2").Value
```

which is much more robust

Finally I advise you to use fully qualified ranges for ranges without an explicit name e.g. `ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` rather than `Range("A1")`
You can use (note the dot-Range on AG2)

```
With ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

   Range("Ordernummerbereik").Value = .Range("AG2").Value
   ' ... other code with range references
End With
```

Comment: Most likely OP should use `Me`: `Me.Range("A1")` would refer to A1 on the sheet containing the change handler.

Comment: Thank you (all). There is still no solution. It seems as if the "Worksheet_Change" is fully ignored, even in its most simple form and in a fresh workbook-woirksheet: when I want it to show a message box after I've entered a value in a cell: nothing happens!

Comment: @Jan Please make a `Sub` that only contains `Application.EnableEvents = True` and run it once. Then check again if the `Worksheet_Change` events runs. If that doesn't help make sure to restart your computer.

Comment: You know what did the job? Restarting my computer! I won't comment on that and the time lost. Thank you very much. Regards. Jan